# how to assign count() to variable

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, numpy

I need to store dates and the count() in a dataframe. I think I have done so in my code, but I am unable to access the count() to assign it to a variable. Ultimately my goal is to group by a number, say 2, and put only dates with count() = 2 in a separate dataframe fro processing.

I have searched and not found a way to access the count() to be able to isolate it and assign it a variable. thanks

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
#conn = sqlite3.connect('data3.db')
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///C:\data3.db', echo=False)



#create_local table()
name = 'Bob'
startDate = pd.to_datetime('10/02/2019').date()
endDate = pd.to_datetime('10/09/2019').date()
d = pd.date_range(start=startDate, end=endDate, freq='D')

dd = pd.DataFrame({'Date': d, 'Name':[name]*len(d)})
#print (dd)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dd, columns =['Date'])
#print(df1)

# PUll data from database
#query = "select Date from testtablee"
#df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
dates= {'Date':['2019-10-07','2019-10-06','2019-11-03','2019-11-02','2019-10-09','2019-10-08','2019-10-07','2019-10-06','2019-10-05','2019-10-04','2019-10-03','2019-10-02']}
df=pd.DataFrame(dates)
df['Date']=df['Date'].astype(str)
df['Date']=df['Date'].str.slice(0,10)

#create column and count
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Date'])
#counts = df2['Date'].value_counts()
#df2.columns = ['Date','count']
#df2['count']=df2.groupby('Date')['Date'].transform('count')
df2= df2.groupby("Date").agg({"Date": np.sum, "Date": pd.Series.count})
print (df2)
# extract the dates with 2 counts into new dataframe

'''
df1['Date']=df2['Date']
df1['dateMatch']=np.where(df1.Date == df2.Date, 'True', 'False')
print (df1)
'''
# Write to the database

#dd.to_sql(name='testtablee', con=engine, if_exists='append')
#engine.execute("SELECT * FROM testtablee").fetchall()
```

my expected outcome is to have a dataframe with only dates that have more than 2 occurrences or counts.

Comment: hello, could you show your input dataframe and your output dataframe? keep in mind that to help you we need to execute code

Comment: I have tried ```df2.columns = ['Date','count']``` but get errors

Comment: @ansev understood and changed, I added an input table. I don't have an output dataframe, as that  is what I am struggling with. I am a self taught python user, so my vocabulary is limited. Thank you.

Comment: I would like the output to be similar to this, but I tried it and I get errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893176/how-to-assign-a-value-count-output-to-a-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Try doing your group by like this:

```
df2 = df2.groupby("Date")["Date"].agg(["count"])
```

Then filter the results to where `count == 2`:

```
df3 = df2.loc[df2['count'] == 2]
print (df3)
```

results:

```
2019-10-06      2
2019-10-07      2
```

Edit:
You can turn the index into a column like this:

```
df3['Date'] = df3.index
```

and then drop the date index of you would like:

```
df3 = df3.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Final Results:

```
   count        Date
0      2  2019-10-06
1      2  2019-10-07
```

Comment: That works great. I just noticed it is turning the date into an index, is there a way to change that? index= false or something similar?

Comment: Updated answer for turning index into a column so you can use it as such

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves my problem. Later I will compare df1 to df2 for duplicates and reject df1 if true.

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///C:\\\\\data3.db', echo=False)



#create_local table()
name = 'Bob'
startDate = pd.to_datetime('10/02/2019').date()
endDate = pd.to_datetime('10/09/2019').date()
d = pd.date_range(start=startDate, end=endDate, freq='D')
dd = pd.DataFrame({'Date': d, 'Name':[name]*len(d)})
#print (dd)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dd, columns =['Date'])


# PUll data from database
dates= {'Date':['2019-10-07','2019-10-06','2019-11-03','2019-11-02','2019-10-09','2019-10-08','2019-10-07','2019-10-06','2019-10-05','2019-10-04','2019-10-03','2019-10-02']}
df=pd.DataFrame(dates)
df['Date']=df['Date'].astype(str)
df['Date']=df['Date'].str.slice(0,10)

#create column and count
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Date'])
df2= df2.groupby("Date").agg({"Date": np.sum, "Date": pd.Series.count}).rename(columns={'Date': 'count'})

# extract the dates with 2 counts into new dataframe
df2=df2.loc[df2['count'] == 2]
print (df2)
```

Comment: dang, its not completely right, I'm showing df2 as only having 1 column still, Count...Why cant I get Date and Count columns?